# Firebase through Golang on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, go, google-cloud-platform

I have a Firebase database that looks like this:

```
{
  "users" : [ null, {
    "name" : "John",
    "recipes" : {
      "34" : {
        "name" : "Chicken Parmesan"
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

I'm trying to access the data through a Golang API. When I'm running the API locally, it works. However, when I try to use the API on AppEngine, Firebase returns null.

This is how I'm calling it:

```
userID := req.URL.Query().Get("user_id")

// Make call to API or to Database here, and then write out results
var user interface{}


f.Auth(<FIREBASE_SECRET>)


if err := f.Child("users/" + userID).Value(&user); err != nil {
    fmt.Print(w, err)
}

json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)
```

Any ideas on why this may not be working?

Comment: HI , which lib are  you  using  to interact with firebase?
why you are trying to encode the the result to interface and not to struct ?

Comment: I'm using [firego](https://github.com/zabawaba99/firego). I'll use a struct eventually, right now we haven't defined exactly what our data will look like, so I was just unmarshalling to an interface for now.

Comment: Its look like you need to pass pointer of map 
var v map[string]interface{} in order to get value
https://github.com/zabawaba99/firego#querying